# Understanding the "Not found: Dataset ### was not found in location US" error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I know this topic has come up many times but still here I am. Data processing location seems consistent (dataset, US; query: US) and I am using backticks & long format in the FROM clause

Below are two sequences of code. The first one works perfectly:

```
SELECT station_id
FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_stations`
```

Whereas the following returns an error message:

```
SELECT bikeshare_stations.station_id
FROM `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare`
```

Not found: Dataset glassy-droplet-347618:bigquery-public-data was not found in location US

My question, thus, is why do the first lines of text work while the second doesn't?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the different parts of the backticks:

1. `bigquery-public-data` is the name of the project;
2. `austin_bikeshare` is the name of the schema (aka dataset in BQ); and
3. `bikeshare_stations` is the name of the table/view.

Therefore, the shorter format you are looking for is: `austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_stations` (instead of `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare`).

Using `bigquery-public-data.austin_bikeshare` means that you have a schema called `bigquery-public-data` that contains a table called `austin_bikeshare` , when this is not true.

Comment: Thanks for answering, with you reply and some more research I came to the following conclusions, please correct me if I am wrong.

1) Last part of a FROM-clause must always refer to a specific table (i.e. that it can not refer to a dataset)?

2) FROM-clause requires full reference to function without errors (project-dataset-table)

Comment: 1) Exactly, if the last part of the FROM clause refers to a dataset, BigQuery will treat it as if it was a table and won't probably find it. 2) If I am not mistaken, you can select, somewhere in the BQ UI, a project. If, for instance, you have the 'bigquery-public-data' project selected, you wouldn't need to state it in the FROM clause and just use `austin_bikeshare.bikeshare_stations`.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved!  I will check your suggestion for 2)

Comment: No worries! Glad I could help :)